# Avoiding Nagios commands.cfg

Tags: nagios

I want to call a command directly from a Nagios service file, instead of passing arguments clumsily to commands.cfg. For example I want do this:

```
define service {
    service_description           footest
    check_command                 $USER1$/check_http example.com -u   http://example.com/index.html
    use generic-service
    host_name                     example
}
```

But I get a:

```
Error: Service check command '/usr/share/nagios/libexec/check_http example.com -u http://example.com/index.html' specified in service 'footest' for host 'example' not defined anywhere!
```

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible. And what is profit?

Comment: Note that -u is not expecting a full URL, but rather a path like /index.html or similar. Also be sure to understand the distinction between -H and -I (and that you might need both in some cases).

Answer (score 5):

If you absolutely insist on doing this, which is a really, really terrible idea, this snippet *should* work:

```
define command {
    command_name check_by_arbitrary_path
    check_command /bin/sh -c "$ARG1$"
}

define service {
    use remote-service
    host_name example
    service_description This is a bad idea, seriously
    check_command check_by_arbitrary_path!$USER1$/check_http example.com -u http://example.com/index.html
}
```

Seriously, though, please don't.

Answer (score 1):

Nagios best practice is to split your check into a command and check, a check_command is defined as a command like

```
define command {
    command_name footest
    command_line $USER1$/footest -a some-fixed-option -b $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
}
```

before it should be used in a service check.

Comment: Yep!  I'd add that you can also do `$USER1$/footest $ARG1$` if you don't have a reasonable ability to guess what parameters might be required; you can then use a check_command like `footest!-b something -c something`.

Answer (score 1):

I have had success with a check_any command definition in commands.cfg

```
define command {
  command_name check_any
  command_line $USER1$/check_$ARG1$
}
```

Which I use in a definition like:

```
define service {
  service_description  Forest is not on fire
  check_command        check_any!forest --on-fire=false
  use                  generic-service
  host_name            example
}
```

Comment: looks pretty insecure. So anyone with local access can run any command with nagios privilege, tell me you are not running nagios as root.

Comment: No, Nagios does not run as root. Nagios runs with significantly less privilege than any other local user. Not sure why this deserves a down-vote; it directly answers the question asked, and another user also posted this same answer and got an up-vote.

Comment: idk, maybe it's because he warned not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break it into two parts, the first the check_command and the second the check itself.

Create the template to check a URL:

```
define command {
     command_name          check_http_url
     command_line          $USER1$/check_http -I'$HOSTADDRESS$' -u '$ARG1$' 
     }
```

Use the template to check a specific URL (www.example.com in this case):

```
define service {
    host_name              example
    service_description    Check www.example.com URL
    check_command          check_http_url!www.example.com
    use                    generic-service
    }
```